# Comparing DateTimes in C# producing unexpected results

Tags: c#, datetime-comparison

Im trying to compare if a runtime variable is within now and one minute from now. Here is the code:

```
if (RunTime.ToUniversalTime() >= now.ToUniversalTime() && 
    RunTime.ToUniversalTime() < now.AddMinutes(1).ToUniversalTime())
{
    //Do Stuff 
}
```

However this evaluates to true a minute before I would expect. for instance if I have my runtime as 9:30 it evaluates to true from 9:29 to 9:30 not 9:30 - 9:31. What Am I missing here? The way I understand the code is that it would evaluate to true when runtime is greater than or equal to now and less than now plus one minute.

Comment: I assume `now` equals `DateTime.Now` just before the code posted?

Comment: Yes, I just have now set as a variable because this is in a foreach loop and I want now to be the same for each item that is iterated.

Comment: What time zones are you working with (are they both the same)? Does the `ToUniversalTime()` calls give you the values you are expecting?

Comment: You are using two different now times.  They may be close but not exactly the same.  Always set now to a variable so both now are the same.

Comment: @jdweng `now` is a variable.

Comment: @krill I only need to work with PT, although I'm covering to Universal just to be safe. Universal is 7 hours before pt but this should not make a difference because all values are being converted.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in there, what are each of the values showing you? If this is on a server, and the `RunTime` is coming from the client, there could be some conversion happening.

Comment: Just ran the code with a break point. now.ToUniversalTime() evaluates to: {4/21/2016 5:09:00 PM} and Runtime.ToUniversalTime() evaluates to: {4/21/2016 5:10:00 PM}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RunTime.ToUniversalTime() >= now.ToUniversalTime() && 
RunTime.ToUniversalTime() < now.AddMinutes(1).ToUniversalTime()
```

Let us rewrite this condition:

```
now.ToUniversalTime() <= RunTime.ToUniversalTime() &&
now.ToUniversalTime() > RunTime.AddMinutes(-1).ToUniversalTime()
```

So when `RunTime` is 9:30, then condition should be true from `RunTime.AddMinutes(-1)` (9:29) exclusive to `RunTime` (9:30) inclusive. Just like you say it is in your post.

If you what that condition be true from 9:30 to 9:31, than you should use different condition:

```
now.ToUniversalTime() >= RunTime.ToUniversalTime() &&
now.ToUniversalTime() < RunTime.AddMinutes(1).ToUniversalTime()
```

Comment: Thank You! This logic was a little bit fuzzy to me.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using `DateTime.Now` you're never going to land precisely on the exact same time. Consider these two cases:

```
Case 1 (what you're experiencing)
now:     9:29:01
runtime: 9:30:00
now+1:   9:30:01

Case 2 (what you want but doesn't work)
now:     9:30:01
runtime: 9:30:00
now+1:   9:31:01
```

Try setting your now variable explicitly and make some logical tables of what should happen. You will get better insight to the rule you want to create.

Comment: Specifically, holding a copy of now in a variable might help. For example, nowCopy = (int)(now), compare nowCopy and nowCopy + 1.  So having a copy, temporary variable which does not move forward with the ticking of time.

Comment: The OP already IS holding `Now` in a variable. He said: "I just have now set as a variable because this is in a foreach loop and I want now to be the same for each item that is iterated. –"

Comment: @MatthewWatson right but is OP setting it as a pointer to a date time which is ticking away in the background?

Comment: Or is it in a variable which stays the same?

Comment: I would bet his `now` is just a `DateTime` struct.

Comment: He's already saving it off. Even then the cases above can happen.

Comment: @Steve_at_IDV Yep, they can - I was just replying to Max.

Comment: Yes now is just a dateTime struct and is not a pointer to DatTime.Now. So yes It is a constant Time.

Comment: @Steve Yes I agree. my logic needs work, but this still does not explain why runtime evaluates to > now when now is a time later than runtime

Answer (score 1):

The following code works as expected (i.e it prints "Second true" and not "First true"):

```
DateTime nine29  = new DateTime(2015, 01, 01, 09, 29, 00);
DateTime nine30  = new DateTime(2015, 01, 01, 09, 30, 00);
DateTime runtime = nine30;

if (runtime.ToUniversalTime() >= nine29.ToUniversalTime() && runtime.ToUniversalTime() < nine29.AddMinutes(1).ToUniversalTime())
    Console.WriteLine("First true");

if (runtime.ToUniversalTime() >= nine30.ToUniversalTime() && runtime.ToUniversalTime() < nine30.AddMinutes(1).ToUniversalTime())
    Console.WriteLine("Second true");
```

Therefore we must assume that you are mistaken when you say *"if I have my runtime as 9:30 it evaluates to true from 9:29 to 9:30 not 9:30 - 9:31."*

Put all your times into variables and print them out to the debug window or the console, or run it under the debugger and inspect them. And pay attention to the seconds!

Comment: Try with that value: `DateTime nine2901  = new DateTime(2015, 01, 01, 09, 29, 01);`

Comment: Here I use a breakpoint when my if evaluates to true:
?RunTime.ToUniversalTime()
{4/21/2016 5:33:00 PM}
    Date: {4/21/2016 12:00:00 AM}
    dateData: 5247654586227387904
    Day: 21
    DayOfWeek: Thursday
    DayOfYear: 112
    Hour: 17
    InternalKind: 4611686018427387904
    InternalTicks: 635968567800000000
    Kind: Utc
    Millisecond: 0
    Minute: 33
    Month: 4
    Second: 0
    Ticks: 635968567800000000
    TimeOfDay: {17:33:00}
    Year: 2016

Comment: ?now.ToUniversalTime()
{4/21/2016 5:32:03 PM}
    Date: {4/21/2016 12:00:00 AM}
    dateData: 5247654585659202448
    Day: 21
    DayOfWeek: Thursday
    DayOfYear: 112
    Hour: 17
    InternalKind: 4611686018427387904
    InternalTicks: 635968567231814544
    Kind: Utc
    Millisecond: 181
    Minute: 32
    Month: 4
    Second: 3
    Ticks: 635968567231814544
    TimeOfDay: {17:32:03.1814544}
    Year: 2016

Comment: So yes It really is evaluating to true when now is < Runtime

Comment: @user3839756 *So yes It really is evaluating to true when now is < Runtime* You ask it yourself: `RunTime.ToUniversalTime() >= now.ToUniversalTime()`.

Comment: Excuse me I meant to say when Runtime < now.

Comment: @user3839756 Runtime (4/21/2016 5:33:00 PM) < now (4/21/2016 5:32:03 PM)?

Comment: RunTime.ToUniversalTime() was 5:33:00 PM and now.ToUniversalTime() was 5:32:03, so it satisfied both condition. Wouldn't it be simpler just to subtract (Runtime - now ).TotalSeconds < 60.0?

Comment: Ok, Yes Im seeing this now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I like to use type TimeSpan when doing date-time comparisons.

```
TimeSpan timeSpan = Runtime.ToUniversalTime().Subtract(now.ToUniversalTime());

if (timeSpan > 0 && timeSpan <= 1)
{
   //Code here
}
```